# Lookup User field limit

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column

Is there any limit of lookup user field in ShP list(Sharepoint Online)? I've created just a simple list with over 18 single user select fields and everything seems to works fine, but I've seen somewhere that the lookup limit is 12. Could someone explain how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/SharePoint-too-many-lookup-columns-cause-query-failure-PowerApps/td-p/12211

> This applies to SharePoint online too. Lists created before this
>   timeline in SharePoint online will share the List View Lookup
>   Threshold set to Default =8. Lists created after this timeline in
>   SharePoint online, will have List View Lookup Threshold set to Default
>   =12.
>
> With on-premises SharePoint, these throttles and limits can be
>   changed on the Resource Throttling page in Central Administration. But
>   on SharePoint online, increasing the List View Threshold is not
>   permitted.
>
> Hope this could help.
>
> Regards,
>
> Mona Li
>
> Community Support Team _ Mona Li

Please note that the max of 12 lookup fields is PER View , the max for a list is 96 lookup fields