# Set up thresold limit for lookup fields

Tags: 2013, threshold

In a SharePoint2013-K2 project, we have a large table with many lookup fields. We currently get exactly 12 lookup fields and therefore get an error message in K2. Now my question is: How does an upbringing of the thresold from 12 fields by default to 20 affect the SharePoint environment?

Comment: chech this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257097/lookup-user-field-limit

Answer (score 1):

Those can be changed via central admin settings. But be aware that increasing the lookup threshold has an adverse effect on the performance.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2013/12/02/sharepoint-20102013-list-view-lookup-threshold-uncovered/

https://sympmarc.com/2012/07/23/sharepoints-list-view-lookup-threshold-and-why-we-dont-change-it/